# Searching a string array of names and grades and listing names associated with grade

Tags: arrays, vb.net, loops

The exercise for this specific problem is that I must display the amount of students based on the selected Grade value in the listbox, and also display the number of students of the selected grade in the number label: [Form Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKU25.png).

I can add the numbers up for the grades just fine, the problem I keep running into is searching the Name array at the same time as the Grade array and getting each individual name to show up based on the grade selected.

I know that each index value of the Grade letter would correspond to the Name array, but I don't know how to get the Index value of the Grade array since it's a string.

EDIT: Here is exactly what the assignment is calling for:

> a. The procedure declares and initializes two parallel one-dimensional arrays named strNames and strGrades.
>   Code the procedure to display the names of students who have earned the grade selected in the lstGrades control. It should also display the number of students who have earned that grade.
>
> b. The first item in the lstGrades control should be selected when the interface appears. Code the appropriate procedure.
>
> c. The contents of the lstNames and lblNumber controls should be cleared when a different grade is selected in the lstGrades control. Code the appropriate procedure.
>
> d.  Save the solution and then start and test the application.

```
Private Sub btnDisplay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDisplay.Click
    ' Display the names and number of students earning a specific grade.

    Dim strNames() As String = {"Helen", "Peter", "Yolanda", "Carl", "Jennifer", "Charles", "Addison", "Aiden", "Treyson", "Sydney", "Jacob", "Nancy", "George", "Ursula", "Jack"}
    Dim strGrades() As String = {"A", "B", "B", "A", "D", "F", "A", "B", "A", "B", "F", "C", "C", "B", "D"}

    Dim intNumGrades(4) As Integer

    ' searches through each value in strGrade array, counter is added for each instance
    For Each strGradeLetter As String In strGrades
        Select Case strGradeLetter
            Case "A"
                intNumGrades(0) += 1
            Case "B"
                intNumGrades(1) += 1
            Case "C"
                intNumGrades(2) += 1
            Case "D"
                intNumGrades(3) += 1
            Case "F"
                intNumGrades(4) += 1
        End Select
    Next strGradeLetter

    lblNumber.Text = intNumGrades(lstGrades.SelectedIndex).ToString
End Sub
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour].  If you used a `For n` loop, the indexer (`n`) will point to the corresponding name array (or you could use Array.IndexOf).  Presumably you will need another collection to store the names for each letter grade

Comment: I can't use Array.IndexOf, and by that I mean I have to complete this exercise without the use of it.

Comment: Please read [Ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I filled the Grades list box at designed time with A B C D F'
lbStudents is a list box.
What the problem calls lstGrades I called lbGrades. No difference 
Except name.

```
 Public Class Form1
        Private Sub lbGrades_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lbGrades.SelectedIndexChanged
            'Clear the list before adding new students
            lbStudents.Items.Clear()
            Dim strNames() As String = {"Helen", "Peter", "Yolanda", "Carl", "Jennifer", "Charles", "Addison", "Aiden", "Treyson", "Sydney", "Jacob", "Nancy", "George", "Ursula", "Jack"}
            Dim strGrades() As String = {"A", "B", "B", "A", "D", "F", "A", "B", "A", "B", "F", "C", "C", "B", "D"}
            'Using a variable for the size of your arrays makes the code more generic so it could be
            'used for different size arrays.
            Dim n As Integer = strGrades.Count - 1
            Dim itgCount As Integer = 0
            'This and the matching .EndUpdate prevents the list box from repainting on each iteration
            'Not important in this example but could be very important for long list additions
            lbStudents.BeginUpdate()
            'loop through the idexes of the arrays
            'VB arrays are zero based = the first element is index 0
            For index As Integer = 0 To n
                'Check the grades array for the item selected in the list box
                If strGrades(index) = lbGrades.SelectedItem Then
                    'if found, increment the counter
                    itgCount += 1
                    'find the name of the student by using the same index as the grades array
                    'this is the value of parallel arrays
                    'Add the name to the other list box
                    lbStudents.Items.Add(strNames(index))
                End If
            Next
            lbStudents.EndUpdate()
            'Display the count in a label using an interpolated string
            lblCount.Text = $"The number of students with Grade {lbGrades.SelectedItem} is {CStr(itgCount)}."
        End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'This satisfies the requirement in b. of the problem
        lbGrades.SelectedItem = "A"
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was stuck on.

I think I gimped myself because I wanted to use a Select Case statement, but a simple If/Else statement seemed to have done the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating Array of Strings, create a List of your own defined class.

Create a class Student for example, with properties: Name, Grade and then assign the values to each object for each student and then add them to the list. Then on that list, you can write a LINQ Query.

You can learn more on how to do this at here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/concepts/linq/basic-query-operations

**EDIT**

If you want to use just arrays then change the foreach loop to for loop and do something like:

```
For index As Integer = 0 To (strGrades.Length -1)
    Select Case strGrades(index)
            Case "A"
                intNumGrades(0) += 1
            Case "B"
                intNumGrades(1) += 1
            Case "C"
                intNumGrades(2) += 1
            Case "D"
                intNumGrades(3) += 1
            Case "F"
                intNumGrades(4) += 1
        End Select
    Next
```

And you can use the index to access your other corresponding array.

If you want to just display them then you can append all names to string Eg: In case for "A" `gradeAStudent += strNames(index) + " "`

Alternatively, you can append them to a list:
`studentList.Add(strNames(index))`

Comment: A List(of T) is a much better choice, but I am pretty sure this is homework with the point of working with arrays

Comment: Have a read here. you might find it insightful .. [Open letter to Students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: This is not an homework assignment, but a exercise at the end of the chapter for my Visual Basic book. I've re-added what the exercise is exactly calling for in my main post.

Comment: The question is a bit garbled and unclear but I think she wants to also collect the names of those who got each letter grade based on `the problem I keep running into is searching the Name array at the same time`

Comment: @Plutonix Since in for loop he/she will have index of which element in grades array she is at, she can use that to get the name at that index like: `strNames(index)` and use it as he/she wants.

Comment: [I know](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46796318/searching-a-string-array-of-names-and-grades-and-listing-names-associated-with-g/46796449?noredirect=1#comment80539456_46796318).  But the *question* is how to collect those names

Comment: That's real simple, just create a list for each category and just append to it or if you don't want to use list, just append all names to one string with space if you are just going to display them